# AWS Build a Modern Web Application : not able to complete step 4/C in module 2B

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, nlb

I am trying to complete AWS' Build A Modern Web Application at https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/ and am having trouble completing part C (test the service) of Step 4 in Module 2B of the tutorial. Specially, I cannot open the link `http://mysfits-nlb-123456789-abc123456.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mysfits` (when I replace the nlb link with mine, that is--I know the exact link there is just a placeholder) in the Cloud9 IDE preview (`Unable to load http preview`) or on my browser on my laptop. Just to confirm it is not an issue with my specific network, I tried opening the link on my phone after cutting my phone off the specific network (i.e., killing wifi) and just as expected, that did not work as well.

I have followed the instructions in the tutorial but I think there is no way this NLB allows access from the Internet, but I do not know how to fix this as my NLB is `internet-facing` and my target group containers have not failed healthchecks. I checked the VPC that the NLB belongs in, and it allows all traffic inbound from `0.0.0.0/0` and outbound to `0.0.0.0/0`, the NLB's DNS is resolvable (`nslookup` or `ping` is able to resolve the DNS to the public IPv4 of my NLB, but both `ping` and `traceroute` from my laptop fail). In addition, the security group that pertains to the target group also allow all access from the Internet.

I also ran wireshark on my local machine to understand how (if at all) the NLB is responding (i.e., checking if I am getting a TCP RST for the SYNs from my laptop. I don't see *any* TCP SYN/ACK coming back from the NLB, nor do I even see a TCP RST, suggesting that the NLB, despite appearances (scheme is `internet-facing`), is *not* publicly accessible.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Lastly, why is this tutorial asking to front this service with an NLB instead of an ALB? I know this shouldn't matter, but it can be confusing.